# Vim and muscle memory

Tags: vim

I made in my vimrc an abbreviation because I want to only write "foo" to write "bar", and thence I mapped "bar" to "NOPE" so that I would be punished if I tried to write directly "bar".

```
iabbrev foo bar
inoremap bar NOPE
```

The result though is when I write "foo", vim replaces it with "NOPE". How can I work on my muscle memory and punish me if I write "bar", because the way I did it does not seem to work ? Note that I usually do not want to type "bar" alone, but "bar{}", and thence an abbreviation like "iabbrev bar NOPE" would not work for me.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? What do you expect to happen when you type `bar{}`?

Comment: Close voters: This question is perfectly on-topic. How is it not about Ubuntu?

Comment: Don't use Vim so don't have a clue - is [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_abbreviations) helpful/relevant? (N.B. for some reason your question is being voted as 'unclear' in the close vote queue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying this, I found typing bar would replace but barf would not. The f is a different type of character from {.

If you add { to non-keyword characters by `:set iskeyword+={` it works. This may have other consequences as described by `:help iskeyword`.

Another way might be to write a function as described in `:help abbreviations`.